# How to change a SoundPool

Tags: android, kotlin, soundpool

I am developing an ear training app and want to let the user decide what kind of sounds the want to identify (different instruments, synth sounds etc.)

So as a "dummy sound" I have a sonar-like ping which I load in a SoundPool:

```
open class PingSoundPool(context: Context) {

    open var mAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
        .build()

    open var mSoundPool = SoundPool.Builder()
        .setMaxStreams(9)
        .setAudioAttributes(mAttributes)
        .build()

    open var babping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.ab830ping, 1)
    open var aaping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.a220ping, 1)
    open var abbping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.bb233ping, 1)
    open var abping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.b247ping, 1)
[and others]

open fun loadPings(note: Int) {
    println(note.toString())
    if (note == 0) {}
    if(note == 1)
        mSoundPool.play(acping, 2.55f, 2.55f, 1, 0, 1f)
    if(note == 2)
    mSoundPool.play(adbping, 2.5f, 2.5f, 1, 0, 1f)
    if(note == 3)
        mSoundPool.play(adping, 2.45f, 2.45f, 1, 0, 1f)
    if(note == 4)
        mSoundPool.play(aebping, 2.4f, 2.4f, 1, 0, 1f)
[and so on]
}
```

Now I make this accessible within my activity:

```
companion object {
    lateinit var pingSoundPool: PingSoundPool
}
```

And in onCreate doing `pingSoundPool = PingSoundPool(this)`

Like this, I can play any of these sounds with `FullscreenActivity.pingSoundPool.loadPings(note: Int)`

Now the problem comes when I want to change the sound. The first step is to create a preference item giving me a string with the desired sound ("ping", "pong", "flute", "violin" etc.). Second step is getting said string and making the SoundPool load accordingly.

Now if i try putting this -

```
val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
val pingsound = sharedPreferences.getString("pingsound", "")

if(pingsound == "ping"){
    open var babping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.ab830ping, 1)
    open var aaping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.a220ping, 1)
    open var abbping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.bb233ping, 1)
    open var abping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.b247ping, 1)
[etc]
}
```

- into my SoundPool class, i get an error message, "Expecting a member declaration."/"Function declaration must have a name."

If instead I just copy the content of the whole class and make a new class like this

```
class PongSoundPool(context: Context): PingSoundPool(context) {

    override var mAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
        .build()

    override var mSoundPool = SoundPool.Builder()
        .setMaxStreams(9)
        .setAudioAttributes(mAttributes)
        .build()

    open var babping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.othersound1, 1)
    open var aaping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.othersound2, 1)
    open var abbping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.othersound3, 1)
    open var abping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.othersound4, 1)
```

and assign the value of `pingSoundPool` in my activity like this

```
        val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        val pingsound = sharedPreferences.getString("pingsound", "")

        when (pingsound) {
        "ping" -> pingSoundPool = PingSoundPool(this)
        "pong" -> pingSoundPool = PongSoundPool(this)
    }
```

Then, once I change the preferences to "pong", nothing happens. On restarting the app I get a runtime error:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.FullscreenActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid null AudioAttributes
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid null AudioAttributes
    at android.media.SoundPool$Builder.setAudioAttributes(SoundPool.java:601)
    at com.example.PingSoundPool.<init>(PingSoundPool.kt:16)
    at com.example.PongSoundPool.<init>(PongSoundPool.kt:7)
    at com.example.FullscreenActivity.onCreate(FullscreenActivity.kt:97)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

The line it's pointing to in PingSoundPool is this: `.setAudioAttributes(mAttributes)`

Now I'm out of ideas how to implement this. Anyone got help?

---

Edit: I'm still looking for a solution to this.

I've tried not loading a new SoundPool but accessing the loaded sounds directly from PongSoundPool like this: `override var babping = FullscreenActivity.pingSoundPool.mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.othersound, 1)`

When I do this, I get no crashes, but also the sounds won't load. I get `sample X not READY` in the logcat, even after some minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Your first crash is because of inproper inheritance. If you have implemented `var mAttributes` and var mSoundPool in `PingSoundPool` do not override it on `PongSoundPool`. Also you could improve your architecture by creating not `PingSoundPool` as a parent class. But `BaseSoundPool` with final properties `mAttributes` and `mSoundPool` and with abstract method `fun play(note: Int)`

```
abstract class BaseSoundPool(val context: Context) {

    protected var loadedSoundChannels: IntArray? = null

    private val attributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
        .build()

    final val soundPool = SoundPool.Builder()
        .setMaxStreams(9)
        .setAudioAttributes(attributes)
        .build()

    fun load(rawSoundIds: IntArray) {
        loadedSoundChannels?.run { unload(this) } // todo implement unload fun by yourself
        loadedSoundChannels = IntArray(rawSoundIds.size) {
            soundPool.load(context, rawSoundIds[it], 1)
        }
    }

    abstract fun play(note: Int)
}

class PingSoundPool(context: Context) : BaseSoundPool(context) {
    override fun play(note: Int) {
        loadedSoundChannels?.getOrNull(note)?.let {
            soundPool.play(note, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Also remember that `SoundPool.load` is asyncronous operation, so you could not call play right after load. Also when loading new sound data you should unload previously loaded.
Maybe you will find out usefull my implementation of [SoundPool](https://gitlab.com/olekdia/common/libraries/sound-pool), that is more predictable on different API.